# Django manage.py runserver invalid syntax

Tags: python, django

I am developing a web in Ubuntu using django. Everything works normal. Now, I want to change my computer which use Windows. When I try to runserver, it gives:

```
E:\DEGNet>py manage.py runserver
  File "manage.py", line 14
    ) from exc
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

E:\DEGNet>py
Python 3.6.3 (v3.6.3:2c5fed8, Oct  3 2017, 18:11:49) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
 on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

As shown above, I have installed Python 3.6.3. I have installed django and other necessary library using pip3 too.

Edit: manage.py file, it is a default manage.py that I get when generating the project.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "DEGNet.settings")
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

Comment: Could you also provide `manage.py`?

Comment: I have updated the question with manage.py file content

Comment: Removing the words `from exc` from your `manage.py` file will resolve your issue I think. Try it.

Comment: why did you change generated `manage.py`?

Comment: I didn't change anything. I copied it as it is from my ubuntu PC. It works normal in ubuntu

Comment: I got this error multiple times and the reason behind this error was my environment was not active, this may be a reason for you too.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Edit your `manage.py` file as given below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "DEGNet.settings")
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        )
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

Note that `from exc` is removed from the file. It is not required in the `manage.py` file.

Comment: This might stop the 'invalid syntax' error but it doesn't solve the real issue: you installed Django for Python 3 and now getting an error when you try to run it with Python 2. The real fix is to use the correct Python version.

Answer (score 37):

I faced same problem but now solved with this cmd:

```
python3 manage.py runserver
```

Comment: This is correct solution. If you have both python 2 and python 3 by default python in /usr/bin points to python 2. django would have be installed for python 3 and hence the error. python3 manage.py runserver works with from exc. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: that's a valid solution only if you have both python2 and python3 installed, but the error might happen even if you have just python 2 distribution

Answer (score 7):

1. Make sure that your virtualenv is activated. Suppose the name of your virtualenv is pythonpy, then run these commands:

   > virtualenv pythonpy
   >   workon pythonpy #After running these command, you should see something like this but your file path may be different:  "(pythonpy) C:\Users\ MyDjangoProject \
2. Then go to the project folder which contains manage.py
   (pythonpy) C:\Users\ MyDjangoProject \ #Same path as above
3. Then simple run the server:

   > python manage.py runserver #This will give you the project path to the localhost. Copy and paste the URL in the browser and should work.

Answer (score 3):

Try (from command line):

```
python3 manage.py runserver
```

If I used this (no python**3**) instead:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

the error persisted.  This method allows you to not have to alter manage.py (so you can keep "from exc").

Answer (score 3):

You just forgot to activate the virtual environment , do it like that  :

```
source /home/adel/Dev/Python/DjangoProjects/myproject/venv/bin/activate
```

And than you can run the server :

```
python manage.py runserver
```

Answer (score 2):

i've also got this error but solve it by installing pipenv first,

try run this first

```
pipenv shell django==2.1
```

then you should be able to run

```
python3 manage.py runserver
```

Answer (score 2):

Ensure you're running the app from virtualenv i.e if you've created a virtualenv for your project, then activate the venv first.

```
me@debian:~/Desktop/webapp$source venv/bin/activate 
(venv) me@debian:~/Desktop/webapp$python manage.py runserver
```

Answer (score 1):

What's happening is that the wrong version of python is being used, which may not have all the dependencies in your virtualenv. I get this error when using `sudo manage.py`: using `sudo` changes the version of python which is being used to `/usr/bin/python`.

The problem is solved by specifying which version of python to use when using `sudo`:

```
sudo /path/to/my/env/bin/python manage.py makemigrations
```

Answer (score 1):

I have met the same problem, and I find it strange because I have activated the virtualenvironment and set the python3, however, I meet this problem when I use this statement "python manage.py runserver".I use this statement often but I meet this only once, and I restart my virtualenvironment and it runs, hope you wil,too.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue.

Activated venv & ran `python manage.py runserver` wasn't working.

I could see the venv was activated but still it wasn't working. Then tried `python3 manage.py runserver` which got rid of `exc` issue but now it wasnt detecting my installed libraries.

The change I made that broke it was renaming the base folder ( kind of same situation like OP base folder location was different now).

But wait, how does this impact anything?

> A variable that stores a full path to `venv` inside `venv/bin/activate` is
> now no longer valid.

**Resolution**:

1. deactivate venv if already running
2. open venv/bin/activate
3. search for `VIRTUAL_ENV` variable and rename as per the new folder changes made.
4. activate venv `source venv/bin/activate`
5. run `python manage.py runserver`

Tada, everything is back to normal and we can happily enjoy our lemonade.

Answer (score 0):

I've got also the same issue with **Python 3.4.4** and **Django 2.0**. I tried the last solution, nothing works (no need to delete that: `from exc` on the line 14).

Just run your server with:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

Instead of:

```
./manage.py runserver #or '.\manage.py runserver' for Windows
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no problem running this way：

```
sudo ./**(your path)**/bin/python manage.py runserver
```

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem. I solved it by simply specifying the `python` version i.e type `python3 manage.py runserver` instead of `python manage.py runserver`

Answer (score 0):

i re installed the v env

```
virtualenv venv --python=python3.7
```

i insttalled django

it worked

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/24013917)

Comment: @GeorgeZ. An attempt to answer the question (especially one containing a solution that worked for at least one person) should not be deleted from review

Answer (score 0):

I had come out of my virtial environment.

I re-ran `pipenv shell`

Answer (score 0):

Do this first on your command line where your Env folder is found:

```
source Env/bin/activate
```

Then now navigate to your project directory and do:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

It works!!

Answer (score 0):

Just use `python3 manage.py runserver` instead `python manage.py runserver`