# Error in manage.py script when running cron job for django inside docker container

Tags: python, django, docker, cron

I have a docker container runnning a django application that is also running a cron job inside it. The managed command keeps failing due to this error:

Line 14 in manage.py

```
line 14
) from exc
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

My cron job looks like this:

```
0 1 * * 1-5 python manage.py myCommand
```

I tried changing it to this to see if that would do the trick:

```
0 1 * * 1-5 /usr/local/bin/python /absolute/path/to/project/manage.py myCommand
```

Comment: It seems to me installation not getting aware of Django?

Comment: connected: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47880626/django-manage-py-runserver-invalid-syntax

Comment: I manually ran the command (stepping into the container interactively) and it ran fine. Django is installed in the container. I just don't understand why it wouldn't run under cron.

Comment: The invalid syntax is from Python 2. You are using a version of Django that requires Python 3. Change your cron command so that it uses Python 3. If you use a virtual environment, then use the Python from the virtual environment.

Comment: The docker container is using python 3.5. When I run python -V, I get Python 3.5.6

Comment: It looks like your container has Python 2 as well, Python 3.5 wouldn't give the syntax error.

Comment: I will just specify the absolute path to the python 3 executable that is installed, as well as the absolute path to the manage.py script

Answer (score 4):

This is a typical error you get when using a wrong Python version. Following your comment under the question:

> The docker container is using python 3.5. When I run python -V, I get
>   Python 3.5.6

You can see that *your user's* `$PATH` points to Python 3.5.6 when using the shell session *you open*. There is one thing about cron jobs that often leaves people stuck with problems: cron opens a different shell and doesn't have access to your `$PATH`. So in your case it points to Python 2.x.

There are many ways to overcome this. Probably the easiest one is to check where your Python 3 is located by running

```
$ which python3
```

and using the path from the output in your cron command. For example, for my system it would be:

```
0 1 * * 1-5 /usr/bin/python3 manage.py myCommand
```

Comment: Gotcha. Thank you very much for pointing that out. I appreciate it a lot.