# How do I solve this syntax error in manage.py?

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, django, mariadb

I'm running a django app with mariadb. It used to work just fine, however I have left this project idle for a while and now I'm just coming back to it and I can't figure out why it's now breaking.

I get the following error when trying to run python manage.py makemigrations:

```
File "manage.py", line 16

) from exc
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Here's my manage.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""Django's command-line utility for administrative tasks."""
import os
import sys


def main():
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'MyDB.settings')
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Now I'll be honest. I may have a clue what the issue is. I'm not using a venv. And I have multiple installations on this system. The problem being I can't remember what I used for this project. I have python 2.7 and python 3. Python 2.7 runs Django 1.11 and python 3 runs django 2.2.7.

When I run manage.py in python 3 it returns the following:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 15, in <module>
    import MySQLdb as Database
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from . import _mysql
ImportError: libmariadbclient.so.18: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 357, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 47, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 117, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 321, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 204, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 28, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 201, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 110, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 20, in <module>
    ) from err
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module.
Did you install mysqlclient?
```

Now this looks like a database error to me. But I have had this working just fine before with MariaDB. I even performed a full uninstall and reinstall of mariadb by the book from the install guides on the django page and the mariadb page. I'm really at a point of being stuck with this now. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

EDIT: I have tried solutions such as installing pymysql and such from other questions. But I do not seem to be able to find an answer so far

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django manage.py runserver invalid syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47880626/django-manage-py-runserver-invalid-syntax)

Comment: Multiple version of python may cause this issue. Try running python3 manage.py makemigrations.

Comment: @ShivendraPratapKushwaha That's what I did to get the final error message in my post. I'm not sure about that error either. So I guess two parts to my question.

Answer (score 0):

try to run the app using python3 (if you are using python 3.x instead of python only

Comment: I tried doing it on python 3. I got the last error in my main post